# As variable in MYSQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am little new in mysql database. My query is like this and its working fine

```
SELECT visitor_sent * 100 / visitor_quantity as percentage FROM `tbl_orders` WHERE oid =15
```

But I want it extend to use percentage variable in where clause but its not working.

```
SELECT visitor_sent * 100 / visitor_quantity as percentage FROM `tbl_orders` WHERE oid =15 AND percentage < 20
```

its giving me unknown column percentage error. Let me know if anyone here can help me for correct the query.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use HAVING instead of WHERE when you want to check on an alias

```
SELECT visitor_sent * 100 / visitor_quantity as percentage FROM `tbl_orders` WHERE oid =15 HAVING percentage < 20
```

Comment: Note that this is a MySQL special trick. Will not work on other platforms.

Comment: Yes that might be important

Comment: if I use the query with Having, its giving me empty result

Comment: sorry its worked! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Would be nice if you accept the answer then. thanks

Comment: I have done as well upvoted!